# JavaScript code works when inserted via Firebug, but not when inserted in <head>

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code (i) that write several `<div><a href="..."></a></div>` inside the `<div id="subsection">` below. Another javascript code (ii) will define that when an `<a href="...">Text</a>` is clicked, it is transformed into an input box, which will have "Text" as its content.

I know the code (ii) works, because I tested it in a separated page. Also, when I insert it via the Firebug command line, it works, too. But when I write the code in `<head>`, it doesn't work.

What is the problem and how do I make it work?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('list.php', 
        { method : 'list', value : 'user' },
            function(data) {
                $('#subsection').append("<p><a class='editable'>teste</a><input type='text' id='boo' style='display:none'/></p>");
                $("a.editable").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("input").val($(this).text()).focus().show()
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().addClass("edit");

        $("input").keyup(function(event){ 
            var txt = $(this);
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
                txt.parent().find("a").show();
                txt.parent().find("a").text(txt.val());   
                txt.parent().removeClass("edit");
                txt.hide();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
            });
});
</script>

<section id="items">
    <div id="subsection" class="space"></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Ok, I edited to show partially what I'm doing.
Thanks to your help, I made it work.
I get the json content via the getJSON method and mount it.
I think it wasn't working because I loaded the functions inside `$(document).ready()` mounted the `<div>`s, but that modified the DOM. So it wouldn't work. Then I loaded the functions right after I modified the DOM, and it worked.

Thank you all!

Comment: I can't help you without the code. Anyway you are missing the start <body> tag.

Comment: That probably depends on what the JS code is doing. E.g. you cannot access DOM elements before they have been parsed.

Comment: That's most likely because the webpage isn't "ready" when you execute the code in the body. Try placing it at the end of the body.

Comment: I added my real code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED! 
Here is the correct example, if you click on the A you edit the input box passing the link value and hiding the link... if you type enter you hide the input and copy the text to the link.
I have also added a reference to JQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.editable").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("input").val($(this).text()).focus().show()
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().addClass("edit");

        $("input").keyup(function(event){ 
        var txt = $(this);
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
          txt.parent().find("a").show();
          txt.parent().find("a").text(txt.val());   
          txt.parent().removeClass("edit");
          txt.hide();
          alert(txt.val());
        }

        return false;

      });

            });
        });
    </script>

<section id="items">
    <div id="subsection" class="space">
        the other <div>
        <a class="editable">test link</a>
        <input type='text' id='boo' style="display:none"/>
        </div>s go here
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I don't write the divs in my code, but I have a javascript code that will load content from a php script and insert the divs like this:
    $('#subsection').append(the <div>s);

Now, instead of working the way you described, the browser opens the link. Do you understand my problems now?

Comment: To prevent the link from opening, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` (`event` is the first argument passed to every jQuery event handler).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem completely, but helps a lot. So I'm marking it as answer and I expain in my EDIT why it works now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I worked an hour on this strange problem, and I also learned some tricks from your code!

Answer (score 4):

It's probably an issue of trying to manipulate the DOM before it's ready. Typically, I would handle this with jQuery's `$(document).ready` event handler, but if you don't want to go that route, it may be enough just to put your code in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page (just before `</body></html>`).

Post your actual script. Seeing it may allow for some better answers.

Comment: Where do you include the jQuery library?

Comment: The code I wrote here is simplified. Please, read what I answered to the user contam below.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery?
Do you execute your code on the document.ready or document.onload event or immediately?
Are you sure that your code finds something when executed? 
Wait for the load evet and execute it.
Add to this post the a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code in head is executed before the HTML body is fully loaded which can break some getElementById logic, you can put the code in a function and then use: onload="yourFunction();" in your body tag